# Regex exclude multiple words in the middle of string

Tags: regex

I have a regex which works well for finding a date and three sets of initials in the one sentence.

```
/^(\d{1,2}[/.-]\d{1,2}[/.-])(\d{2}|\d{4})(\s[A-Z]{2,5}\s[A-Z]{2,5}\s[A-Z]{2,5})$/;
```

working example  **28/05/2018 SB GL PA**

However, sometimes there can be **multiple words of any number** which may appear between the date and first initials eg 28/05/2018 **ENG APP PROJ APPROVE ETC ETC** SB GL PA

The bolded words need to be ignored in the regex, I am thinking that a negative look ahead may work, but need help as there could be any number of words between the date and initials.

If anyone can please help with modifying the regex so that a match is found for the date and three sets of initials regardless of what string is in between I will be most grateful  - thank you

Comment: The solution could be really simple; maybe try putting `|` between each capture group (eg. `( ... )|( ... )|( ... )`).

Comment: How exactly do you want to use this regex (at least the language/tool would be helpful). You could match the stuff between by something as simple as `.*?` and then refer to your capturing groups instead of the full match.

Comment: I am using the regex in Adobe javascript to find words in a pdf file.  Can you please show me a working example of the regex, as I am a relative beginner.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `^(\d{1,2}[\/.-]\d{1,2}[\/.-])(\d{4}|\d{2}).*?(\s[A-Z]{2,5}\s[A-Z]{2,5}\s[A-Z]{2,5})$`

Replace with: `$1$2$3`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX5NpL/2)

Explanation:

$1 has the value of the 1st capturing group, in this case `(\d{1,2}[\/.-]\d{1,2}[\/.-])`

$2 has the value of the 2nd capturing group, in this case `(\d{4}|\d{2})`

$3 has the value of the 3rd capturing group, in this case `(\s[A-Z]{2,5}\s[A-Z]{2,5}\s[A-Z]{2,5})`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help can you please advise what the substitution of $1$2$3 means?